# Validating repeated radio buttons with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I'm new to javascript and I want to validate a nested (repeated) radio buttons. I want it such that onsubmit if one group on a roll is not checked, the browser should prompt the user. please how do I write the code for that?

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="super4_engine.asp" >
   <table width="442" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="6" bgcolor="#50B2FF"><div align="center"><strong>Set 1</strong></div></td>
      </tr>
        <% Dim counter
           While ( ( Repeat1__numRows <> 0 ) AND ( NOT rs_set1.EOF ) )
              counter = counter + 1
        %>
      <tr>
        <td width="20" bgcolor="#FFCCFF"><input type="radio" name="team<%=counter%>" id="radio" value="<%=(rs_set1.Fields.Item("team1").Value)%>" /></td>
        <td width="126" bgcolor="#FFCCFF"><%=(rs_set1.Fields.Item("team1").Value)%>
        <input name="super<%=counter%>" type="hidden" id="super<%=counter%>" value="<%=(rs_set1.Fields.Item("game_id").Value)%>" /></td>
        <td width="20" bgcolor="#FFCCFF"><input type="radio" name="team<%=counter%>" id="radio2" value="<%=(rs_set1.Fields.Item("def_stat").Value)%>" /></td>
        <td width="66" bgcolor="#FFCCFF"><%=(rs_set1.Fields.Item("def_stat").Value)%></td>
        <td width="27" bgcolor="#FFCCFF"><input type="radio" name="team<%=counter%>" id="radio3" value="<%=(rs_set1.Fields.Item("team2").Value)%>" /></td>
        <td width="126" bgcolor="#FFCCFF"><%=(rs_set1.Fields.Item("team2").Value)%></td>
     </tr>

    <%
       Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index + 1
       Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows - 1
       rs_set1.MoveNext()
       Wend
    %>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="6" bgcolor="#50B2FF"><div align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
        </div></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
  <div align="center"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your question, but as Aaron said, we should also "learn" from the answers we get, so... I will give it to you a piece at a time so that you can build it and understand what is going on.

First you need to realize that you are validating radio buttons with different names created dynamically so you need to create a script that will "repeat" itself using the dynamically created names and id's.

Start your script by declaring your javascript "counter" variable and giving it an initial value of zero.

```
<script Language="JavaScript">
<!--
function Form1_Validator(theForm) {
<% Dim jscounter
jscounter = 0
```

Next, we will begin our repeat region for the javascript and increment our javascript counter.

```
While (NOT rs_set1.EOF)
jscounter = jscounter + 1
%>
```

Next, declare your javascript variable making it dynamic by appending the counter variable to the name and give the variable an initial value of "false".

```
var radioSelected<%= jscounter %> = false;
```

Now, iterate through the radio buttons for that row. Notice the jscounter variable has been appended to the name.

```
for (i = 0;  i < theForm.team<%= jscounter %>.length;  i++)
{
```

Next, provide for the two possible instances (checked or not) and how to handle them.

```
if (theForm.team<%= jscounter %>[i].checked)
radioSelected<%= jscounter %> = true;
}
if (!radioSelected<%= jscounter %>)
{
alert("Please select one of the \"team <%= jscounter %>\" options.");
return (false);
}
```

Almost done... Now, end the loop and repeat until all rows of buttons have been created in the javascript.

```
<%
  rs_set1.MoveNext()
Wend
If (rs_set1.CursorType > 0) Then
  rs_set1.MoveFirst
Else
  rs_set1.Requery
End If
%>
```

Finally, we will close out the javascript with an alert to tell us that all validations have been successful.

```
alertsay = "All Validations have succeeded. "
alertsay = alertsay + "This is just a test page. There is no submission page."
alert(alertsay);
return (false);
}
//-->
</script>
```

NOTE: The three "alert" lines above can be removed (if you so choose) after debugging and then change "return (false);" to "true" so that the form will be submitted.

Now let's move on the the HTML of the form.

First, add this line to your opening form tag...

```
onsubmit="return Form1_Validator(this)"
```

Next, begin your repeat region and don't forget to give your counter an initial value of zero.

```
<% Dim counter
counter = 0
While (NOT rs_set1.EOF)
counter = counter + 1
%>
```

Then, change your radio button "id" to make use of the counter variable as you did for the "name" attribute.

```
id="team<%=counter%>"
```

Finally, end the loop and repeat until all rows have been created.

```
<%
  rs_set1.MoveNext()
Wend
If (rs_set1.CursorType > 0) Then
  rs_set1.MoveFirst
Else
  rs_set1.Requery
End If
%>
```

That's it!

Now here is the javascript in it's entirety.

```
<script Language="JavaScript">
<!--
function Form1_Validator(theForm) {
<% Dim jscounter
jscounter = 0
While (NOT rs_set1.EOF)
jscounter = jscounter + 1
%>
var radioSelected<%= jscounter %> = false;
for (i = 0;  i < theForm.team<%= jscounter %>.length;  i++)
{
if (theForm.team<%= jscounter %>[i].checked)
radioSelected<%= jscounter %> = true;
}
if (!radioSelected<%= jscounter %>)
{
alert("Please select one of the \"team <%= jscounter %>\" options.");
return (false);
}<%
  rs_set1.MoveNext()
Wend
If (rs_set1.CursorType > 0) Then
  rs_set1.MoveFirst
Else
  rs_set1.Requery
End If
%>
alertsay = "All Validations have succeeded. "
alertsay = alertsay + "This is just a test page. There is no submission page."
alert(alertsay);
return (false);
}
//-->
</script>
```

And, the form...

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return Form1_Validator(this)" action="super4_engine.asp" >
            <table width="442" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
              <tr>
                <td colspan="6" bgcolor="#50B2FF"><div align="center"><strong>Set 1</strong></div></td>
              </tr>
              <% Dim counter
counter = 0
While (NOT rs_set1.EOF)
counter = counter + 1
%>
              <tr>
                <td width="20" bgcolor="#FFCCFF"><input type="radio" name="team<%=counter%>" id="team<%=counter%>" value="<%=(rs_set1.Fields.Item("team1").Value)%>" /></td>
                <td width="126" bgcolor="#FFCCFF"><%=(rs_set1.Fields.Item("team1").Value)%>
                  <input name="super<%=counter%>" type="hidden" id="super<%=counter%>" value="<%=(rs_set1.Fields.Item("game_id").Value)%>" /></td>
                <td width="20" bgcolor="#FFCCFF"><input type="radio" name="team<%=counter%>" id="team<%=counter%>" value="<%=(rs_set1.Fields.Item("def_stat").Value)%>" /></td>
                <td width="66" bgcolor="#FFCCFF"><%=(rs_set1.Fields.Item("def_stat").Value)%></td>
                <td width="27" bgcolor="#FFCCFF"><input type="radio" name="team<%=counter%>" id="team<%=counter%>" value="<%=(rs_set1.Fields.Item("team2").Value)%>" /></td>
                <td width="126" bgcolor="#FFCCFF"><%=(rs_set1.Fields.Item("team2").Value)%></td>
              </tr>
<%
  rs_set1.MoveNext()
Wend
If (rs_set1.CursorType > 0) Then
  rs_set1.MoveFirst
Else
  rs_set1.Requery
End If
%>
<tr>
                <td colspan="6" bgcolor="#50B2FF"><div align="center">
                  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
                </div></td>
              </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

A working demo can bee seen here... http://siteprevue.net/stackoverflow/radiovalidator.asp

Answer (score 0):

the checked state of radio buttons when first drawn on the page wihtout any clicks is blank.

so if you concatenate the values of team0.checked && team1.checked && team2.checked into a single string value

The concatenated string will contain either "checked" or "", therefore groups that remain unchecked can be validated when the concatenation = "".

validation is passed when the concatenated string = "checked" or length > 0

Comment: i could, but then you wouldnt learn anything.
have a go and i'll correct you as you go along

Comment: I tried this but didn't work out:<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
var one = document.getElementById('team1');


if ( one.checked == false )  
{
alert ( "Please not all Options are selected" );

return false;
  }
}

function checkRadio(name){
  var radio = document.forms.form1[name];
  for (var option in radio){
    if(radio[option].checked){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
</script>